# error: device not found

Tags: android, adb, wireless

When connected to adb wirelessly between computer and phone, the connection will time out after a while. I try to connect back with `adb connect`, but it gives `unable to connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5555`. So using `adb shell` gives `error: device not found`. I tried looking for the process to see if I could kill it with `ps aux | grep adb` but no luck. How do I reconnect adb?

Edit: I should mention I can still connect via usb after this happens. It's judt adb wireless that fails to work after a while.

Comment: Is one going into power save and turning off WiFi?

Comment: No, I keep it plugged into the wall and have "stay awake" checked in developer options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `adb kill-server` to kill the adb server. Then reconnect with `adb connect XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`.